# Threshold choice for Peaks-Over-Threshold

Tags: r, extreme-value, threshold, pareto-distribution

I'm trying to estimate equivalent performances at different events, using Peaks-Over-Threshold from Extreme Value Theory. The challenge is to find the threshold and preferably with same number of exceedances for all events, in order to do a fair comparison.

But I wonder if this even converges into a Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD)? Perhaps there's too little extreme data, so that I'd have to choose a threshold too low to actually make any reliable calculations?

Here's example data:

```
structure(list(logspeed = c(1.46218237815235, 1.45354589247713, 
1.44214539465991, 1.43817730299957, 1.43217077438742, 1.43212889746369, 
1.43179394519126, 1.42991192627561, 1.42615848121503, 1.42470260441621, 
1.42445323822066, 1.42441168323302, 1.42208735561871, 1.42163142540958, 
1.42134139619746, 1.41993387816413, 1.41823920770254, 1.41103797501081, 
1.40625220046084, 1.40592580306912, 1.4031557181953, 1.40266767523784, 
1.40185479923795, 1.40071788178561, 1.40043385427361, 1.40035271837093, 
1.400190466312, 1.39925802751175, 1.39691051358308, 1.39650632619631, 
1.39638510183006, 1.39622349219778, 1.39590035126513, 1.39565806407286, 
1.39319813743669, 1.39118630720032, 1.39102553549579, 1.38974029152419, 
1.38597441230897, 1.38529486078681, 1.38453590810503, 1.38437620196399, 
1.38194383838263, 1.38098846232971, 1.3781277984535, 1.37622522544311, 
1.37519617445386, 1.37487975630464, 1.37223367747156, 1.37144515826968, 
1.36896537899812, 1.36806159285883, 1.36621726169071, 1.36566854332623, 
1.3653159547347, 1.36480687947847, 1.36425893425928, 1.36421980680158, 
1.36218728577666, 1.36035374711954, 1.36019785639862, 1.35988614784359, 
1.35957453642051, 1.35930195605629, 1.35817348540324, 1.35809570676121, 
1.35801793416823, 1.35790128661867, 1.35770690426798, 1.3556487710055, 
1.35533847699945, 1.35502827924589, 1.35479569406052, 1.3546019143874, 
1.35382717098239, 1.35378844956363, 1.35278221858744, 1.35208618979015, 
1.35193158249238, 1.3505797872959, 1.35027106194324, 1.34815115134185, 
1.34811264907984, 1.347920160003, 1.34749681441198, 1.34657377292496, 
1.34653533134654, 1.34634314561766, 1.34622785190681, 1.34611257148706, 
1.34607414763353, 1.34553636864772, 1.34530598044258, 1.34519080624147, 
1.34403979322305, 1.34350310686501, 1.34334982079458, 1.3431199357361, 
1.34300501302149, 1.34212437737542, 1.34017442550634, 1.33986889540925, 
1.33967798649131, 1.33914363533356, 1.33761848919585, 1.33719948147617, 
1.33567729532336, 1.33552520406832, 1.33484107953098, 1.33465112796805, 
1.33332247635379, 1.33241242017085, 1.33120029881032, 1.33093534299961, 
1.33082181199607, 1.33059478864952, 1.33021653090019, 1.3296116159479, 
1.3290448403192, 1.32896929450062, 1.32878045491928, 1.32855389448332, 
1.32794998414565, 1.32753500724636, 1.32681863432478, 1.32602745033324, 
1.32598979051438, 1.32425897020044, 1.32238103537624, 1.32076882723969, 
1.31994498057836, 1.31691756334207, 1.31564952155056, 1.3154631803593, 
1.31520236101248, 1.3148671217789, 1.31215210383962, 1.31200354853964, 
1.31081589994399, 1.31059337277621, 1.3101484669406, 1.30900004219364, 
1.30862986376341, 1.30859285345604, 1.30829682029816, 1.3074831806956, 
1.30726139383187, 1.30722443413641, 1.30622703836469, 1.30622703836469, 
1.30622703836469, 1.30493559675207, 1.30438263192497, 1.30408784232891, 
1.30338806512414, 1.30331443284372, 1.30313037585915, 1.30305676254984, 
1.30290955218596, 1.30261519645494, 1.30206351288663, 1.30184292465044, 
1.30037357861229, 1.29945633248755, 1.29945633248755, 1.29916299132968, 
1.29769757488925, 1.2975877551765, 1.2975511512855, 1.2975511512855, 
1.29641709471721, 1.29579573831279, 1.29528432277653, 1.29506522472927, 
1.29502871305466, 1.29448119784744, 1.29418931226451, 1.29407987713208, 
1.29393398224908, 1.2937881086483, 1.29233054179768, 1.29189368569841, 
1.29185728963645, 1.29167532919415, 1.29142064018625, 1.2910932781755, 
1.2910932781755, 1.29094781834034, 1.29040253232432, 1.29014816723638, 
1.29011183464786, 1.28945807368316, 1.28934915506341, 1.28934915506341, 
1.28858705671584, 1.28797054506419, 1.28778929041905, 1.2877167977589, 
1.28731818203729, 1.28731818203729, 1.28713704558671, 1.28681108263494, 
1.28670245192493, 1.2865214269611, 1.28619566458377, 1.28594236719319, 
1.28554445801975, 1.28431555700847, 1.28395440275557, 1.28341291581925, 
1.282763518293, 1.28243897760537, 1.28081785218954, 1.28042197648934, 
1.2801341652915, 1.27937905477576, 1.2791274779267, 1.27869635052187, 
1.27866043162673, 1.278480856501, 1.27837312690218, 1.27808590469794, 
1.27797821763643, 1.27787054217018, 1.27700955556991, 1.27647181514217, 
1.27643597605965, 1.2762567999111, 1.27600600722577, 1.27568365187994, 
1.27528980307698, 1.2750392527598, 1.27489610932983, 1.27439526862248, 
1.27400192682127, 1.27382318622702, 1.27378744194163, 1.27353726771185, 
1.2731085431608, 1.27178779835441, 1.27171645641246, 1.27164511955981, 
1.27157378779574, 1.27082511131378, 1.27075383801629, 1.2704687956143, 
1.26950737691365, 1.26932943780394, 1.26929385378116, 1.26858243910313, 
1.26858243910313, 1.26833356348632, 1.26829801488249, 1.26815583310285, 
1.26794259833056, 1.26645122670267, 1.26645122670267, 1.26634478521877, 
1.26630930724172, 1.26609646580779, 1.26574183072357, 1.26538732136081, 
1.26471409961512, 1.26467867944333, 1.26435995434103, 1.26404133079206, 
1.26386436156654, 1.26354589586084, 1.26329827041075, 1.26319216398591, 
1.26297998490597, 1.26255576175823, 1.26234371765226, 1.26128417103905, 
1.26110768903093, 1.26103710494761, 1.26019048432417, 1.26019048432417, 
1.26004945054634, 1.25966171018653, 1.25962646851677, 1.25937981159767, 
1.2593093493654, 1.25888668020339, 1.25885146583593, 1.2584993903473, 
1.25811225042658, 1.25790114635149, 1.25786596667127, 1.25776043505566, 
1.25776043505566, 1.25761974355671, 1.25761974355671, 1.25744390701391, 
1.25712747913046, 1.25702202541575, 1.25628416062234, 1.25579255305573, 
1.25568724001261, 1.25565213812939), logdistance = c(4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 
4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809, 4.60517018598809), logtime = c(10.0507430868179, 
10.0593795724931, 10.0707800703103, 10.0747481619707, 10.0807546905828, 
10.0807965675065, 10.081131519779, 10.0830135386946, 10.0867669837552, 
10.088222860554, 10.0884722267496, 10.0885137817372, 10.0908381093515, 
10.0912940395607, 10.0915840687728, 10.0929915868061, 10.0946862572677, 
10.1018874899594, 10.1066732645094, 10.1069996619011, 10.1097697467749, 
10.1102577897324, 10.1110706657323, 10.1122075831846, 10.1124916106966, 
10.1125727465993, 10.1127349986582, 10.1136674374585, 10.1160149513871, 
10.1164191387739, 10.1165403631402, 10.1167019727725, 10.1170251137051, 
10.1172674008974, 10.1197273275335, 10.1217391577699, 10.1218999294744, 
10.123185173446, 10.1269510526613, 10.1276306041834, 10.1283895568652, 
10.1285492630062, 10.1309816265876, 10.1319370026405, 10.1347976665167, 
10.1367002395271, 10.1377292905164, 10.1380457086656, 10.1406917874987, 
10.1414803067005, 10.1439600859721, 10.1448638721114, 10.1467082032795, 
10.147256921644, 10.1476095102355, 10.1481185854918, 10.1486665307109, 
10.1487056581686, 10.1507381791936, 10.1525717178507, 10.1527276085716, 
10.1530393171266, 10.1533509285497, 10.1536235089139, 10.154751979567, 
10.154829758209, 10.154907530802, 10.1550241783516, 10.1552185607023, 
10.1572766939647, 10.1575869879708, 10.1578971857243, 10.1581297709097, 
10.1583235505828, 10.1590982939878, 10.1591370154066, 10.1601432463828, 
10.1608392751801, 10.1609938824778, 10.1623456776743, 10.162654403027, 
10.1647743136284, 10.1648128158904, 10.1650053049672, 10.1654286505582, 
10.1663516920453, 10.1663901336237, 10.1665823193526, 10.1666976130634, 
10.1668128934832, 10.1668513173367, 10.1673890963225, 10.1676194845276, 
10.1677346587288, 10.1688856717472, 10.1694223581052, 10.1695756441756, 
10.1698055292341, 10.1699204519487, 10.1708010875948, 10.1727510394639, 
10.173056569561, 10.1732474784789, 10.1737818296367, 10.1753069757744, 
10.1757259834941, 10.1772481696469, 10.1774002609019, 10.1780843854393, 
10.1782743370022, 10.1796029886164, 10.1805130447994, 10.1817251661599, 
10.1819901219706, 10.1821036529742, 10.1823306763207, 10.18270893407, 
10.1833138490223, 10.183880624651, 10.1839561704696, 10.1841450100509, 
10.1843715704869, 10.1849754808246, 10.1853904577239, 10.1861068306454, 
10.186898014637, 10.1869356744558, 10.1886664947698, 10.190544429594, 
10.1921566377305, 10.1929804843919, 10.1960079016282, 10.1972759434197, 
10.1974622846109, 10.1977231039578, 10.1980583431913, 10.2007733611306, 
10.2009219164306, 10.2021095650262, 10.202332092194, 10.2027769980296, 
10.2039254227766, 10.2042956012068, 10.2043326115142, 10.2046286446721, 
10.2054422842746, 10.2056640711384, 10.2057010308338, 10.2066984266055, 
10.2066984266055, 10.2066984266055, 10.2079898682182, 10.2085428330453, 
10.2088376226413, 10.2095373998461, 10.2096110321265, 10.2097950891111, 
10.2098687024204, 10.2100159127843, 10.2103102685153, 10.2108619520836, 
10.2110825403198, 10.2125518863579, 10.2134691324827, 10.2134691324827, 
10.2137624736405, 10.215227890081, 10.2153377097937, 10.2153743136847, 
10.2153743136847, 10.216508370253, 10.2171297266574, 10.2176411421937, 
10.217860240241, 10.2178967519156, 10.2184442671228, 10.2187361527057, 
10.2188455878381, 10.2189914827211, 10.2191373563219, 10.2205949231726, 
10.2210317792718, 10.2210681753338, 10.2212501357761, 10.221504824784, 
10.2218321867947, 10.2218321867947, 10.2219776466299, 10.2225229326459, 
10.2227772977339, 10.2228136303224, 10.2234673912871, 10.2235763099068, 
10.2235763099068, 10.2243384082544, 10.224954919906, 10.2251361745512, 
10.2252086672113, 10.2256072829329, 10.2256072829329, 10.2257884193835, 
10.2261143823353, 10.2262230130453, 10.2264040380091, 10.2267298003865, 
10.226983097777, 10.2273810069505, 10.2286099079618, 10.2289710622147, 
10.229512549151, 10.2301619466772, 10.2304864873649, 10.2321076127807, 
10.2325034884809, 10.2327912996787, 10.2335464101945, 10.2337979870435, 
10.2342291144484, 10.2342650333435, 10.2344446084692, 10.234552338068, 
10.2348395602723, 10.2349472473338, 10.2350549228, 10.2359159094003, 
10.2364536498281, 10.2364894889106, 10.2366686650591, 10.2369194577445, 
10.2372418130903, 10.2376356618932, 10.2378862122104, 10.2380293556404, 
10.2385301963477, 10.238923538149, 10.2391022787432, 10.2391380230286, 
10.2393881972584, 10.2398169218094, 10.2411376666158, 10.2412090085578, 
10.2412803454104, 10.2413516771745, 10.2421003536565, 10.2421716269539, 
10.2424566693559, 10.2434180880566, 10.2435960271663, 10.2436316111891, 
10.2443430258671, 10.2443430258671, 10.2445919014839, 10.2446274500877, 
10.2447696318674, 10.2449828666397, 10.2464742382676, 10.2464742382676, 
10.2465806797515, 10.2466161577285, 10.2468289991624, 10.2471836342467, 
10.2475381436094, 10.2482113653551, 10.2482467855269, 10.2485655106292, 
10.2488841341782, 10.2490611034037, 10.2493795691094, 10.2496271945595, 
10.2497333009843, 10.2499454800643, 10.250369703212, 10.250581747318, 
10.2516412939312, 10.2518177759393, 10.2518883600226, 10.2527349806461, 
10.2527349806461, 10.2528760144239, 10.2532637547837, 10.2532989964535, 
10.2535456533726, 10.2536161156048, 10.2540387847668, 10.2540739991343, 
10.2544260746229, 10.2548132145436, 10.2550243186187, 10.255059498299, 
10.2551650299146, 10.2551650299146, 10.2553057214135, 10.2553057214135, 
10.2554815579563, 10.2557979858398, 10.2559034395545, 10.2566413043479, 
10.2571329119145, 10.2572382249576, 10.2572733268408), speed = c(4.31536702196522, 
4.27825789338581, 4.22976059555029, 4.21300977418268, 4.18778005779136, 
4.18760469011725, 4.18620227729404, 4.17833117452889, 4.16267743412563, 
4.15662149804639, 4.15558510638298, 4.15541242468315, 4.14576510094938, 
4.14387535222941, 4.1426736815941, 4.13684689529641, 4.12984224002643, 
4.10020911066464, 4.08063331429038, 4.07930162356205, 4.06801724839313, 
4.06603236561763, 4.06272852847973, 4.05811216622027, 4.05695971439004, 
4.05663056265466, 4.05597241938755, 4.05219223599968, 4.04269081500647, 
4.04105714054797, 4.04056729564831, 4.0399143538157, 4.03860910302492, 
4.0376307182945, 4.02771064926696, 4.01961572473672, 4.01896953621092, 
4.01380749779241, 3.99872040946897, 3.996003996004, 3.99297236863121, 
3.9923347173427, 3.98263570831176, 3.97883261051208, 3.96746677246578, 
3.9599255533996, 3.95585268404605, 3.95460117847115, 3.94415082432752, 
3.94104201150784, 3.93128120454456, 3.92772977219167, 3.92049241384718, 
3.91834175776811, 3.91696043869957, 3.91496691852954, 3.91282231873851, 
3.91266922294389, 3.90472471690746, 3.89757181276065, 3.89696426483769, 
3.89574973703689, 3.89453596603965, 3.89347453667653, 3.88908334305604, 
3.88878086719813, 3.88847843838706, 3.88802488335925, 3.88726919339164, 
3.87927690278532, 3.87807337314822, 3.8768705900597, 3.87596899224806, 
3.87521798101143, 3.87221684414327, 3.87206690931619, 3.86817267522822, 
3.86548125241593, 3.86488366700162, 3.85966266548304, 3.85847127368137, 
3.85030032342523, 3.8501520810072, 3.84941104011086, 3.84778175381892, 
3.8442317302887, 3.84408395479357, 3.8433452477036, 3.84290215971101, 
3.84245917387128, 3.84231153461923, 3.84024577572965, 3.83936113030792, 
3.83891896042075, 3.83450285670463, 3.832445483463, 3.83185806797716, 
3.83097728230472, 3.83053704129319, 3.82716521872249, 3.81970970206264, 
3.81854284405071, 3.81781391974955, 3.8157744114168, 3.8099592334362, 
3.80836316551146, 3.80257053768347, 3.80199224393582, 3.79939209726444, 
3.79867046533713, 3.79362670713202, 3.7901758641601, 3.78558449424591, 
3.78458161450252, 3.78415197154318, 3.78329297820823, 3.78186218894183, 
3.77957517575025, 3.77743361160428, 3.77714825306893, 3.77643504531722, 
3.77557955146115, 3.7733001282922, 3.77173462075208, 3.76903361977989, 
3.76605280006026, 3.76591097386458, 3.7593984962406, 3.75234521575985, 
3.74630052822837, 3.74321542204754, 3.73190028362442, 3.72717107715244, 
3.72647661635923, 3.7255048059012, 3.72425607984805, 3.71415837171297, 
3.71360665478313, 3.70919881305638, 3.70837350737966, 3.70672399733116, 
3.70246954718797, 3.70109922647026, 3.70096225018505, 3.69986680479503, 
3.69685767097967, 3.69603784742756, 3.69590124551872, 3.69221680697091, 
3.69221680697091, 3.69221680697091, 3.68745160219772, 3.68541313481241, 
3.68432687348022, 3.68174956739443, 3.68147848175827, 3.68080094228504, 
3.68052999631947, 3.67998822403768, 3.67890515782503, 3.67687612604331, 
3.67606513987428, 3.67066769445362, 3.66730233240428, 3.66730233240428, 
3.66622671946033, 3.66085810513984, 3.66045609282917, 3.66032210834553, 
3.66032210834553, 3.65617344886841, 3.65390236772873, 3.65203418303995, 
3.65123411713159, 3.65110080689328, 3.64910232082908, 3.64803735590252, 
3.64763815429509, 3.64710602137204, 3.64657404368596, 3.64126278993555, 
3.63967242948135, 3.63953996214878, 3.6388777700957, 3.63795110593714, 
3.63676037385897, 3.63676037385897, 3.63623140976692, 3.63424916412269, 
3.63332485557534, 3.63319284987647, 3.63081838646431, 3.63042294427301, 
3.63042294427301, 3.62765725894217, 3.62542145524417, 3.62476439031463, 
3.62450163102573, 3.62305713561103, 3.62305713561103, 3.62240092733464, 
3.62122035125837, 3.62082699688609, 3.62017159613366, 3.61899247249566, 
3.61807590723253, 3.61663652802893, 3.61219476954197, 3.61089044558388, 
3.60893572485474, 3.60659285173297, 3.60542255552351, 3.59958244843598, 
3.59815774323546, 3.59712230215827, 3.59440710254843, 3.59350294667242, 
3.59195402298851, 3.59182500628569, 3.5911800617683, 3.59079320621925, 
3.58976199877948, 3.58937544867193, 3.58898898180383, 3.58590024025532, 
3.58397247509139, 3.58384403110777, 3.58320194926186, 3.58230342109977, 
3.58114883254548, 3.57973867907643, 3.57884188676544, 3.57832963572604, 
3.57653791130186, 3.57513138607844, 3.57449242207606, 3.57436465668227, 
3.57347055460263, 3.57193884840692, 3.56722434273891, 3.56696985910469, 
3.56671541177729, 3.56646100074896, 3.56379187455453, 3.56353788040767, 
3.56252226576416, 3.55909883617468, 3.55846558963775, 3.55833896737003, 
3.55580841304271, 3.55580841304271, 3.55492356914326, 3.55479719881981, 
3.55429180735738, 3.55353398955261, 3.54823829968421, 3.54823829968421, 
3.54786064003406, 3.54773477134849, 3.54697974674565, 3.54572208630288, 
3.54446531740687, 3.54207990932275, 3.54195445046577, 3.54082572055803, 
3.53969770981558, 3.53907134767837, 3.53794445427207, 3.53706847764573, 
3.53669319186561, 3.5359428591634, 3.53444314848196, 3.53369377009788, 
3.52995163966254, 3.52932872167714, 3.52907961603614, 3.52609308885755, 
3.52609308885755, 3.52559582569454, 3.52422907488987, 3.52410487736115, 
3.52323573970334, 3.5229874933944, 3.52149874986794, 3.52137474470033, 
3.52013517319065, 3.51877265209895, 3.51802990325418, 3.51790614226412, 
3.517534911534, 3.517534911534, 3.51704005908627, 3.51704005908627, 
3.51642168928898, 3.51530917144163, 3.51493848857645, 3.51234589582382, 
3.5106196243637, 3.510249929795, 3.51012671557443)), row.names = c(NA, 
-300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here are some plots for the above data:

[image: Mean Residuals Plot]

[image: Threshold Choice Plot]
[image]

Ideally I'd like to use around 150-250 exceedances and then use the same number of exceedandes when comparing with other events. But also trying with thresholds every n=10, it seems like the parameters don't stabilize? The following table includes threshold, shape and scale, for some numbers of exceedances from 150 to 270.

```
[1] "151"     "1.3049"  "-0.5537" "0.0887" 
[1] "160"     "1.3021"  "-0.4925" "0.0815" 
[1] "170"     "1.2964"  "-0.4843" "0.0838" 
[1] "180"     "1.2923"  "-0.4893" "0.0862" 
[1] "190"     "1.2901"  "-0.468"  "0.0842"
[1] "200"     "1.2871"  "-0.4555" "0.0838" 
[1] "210"     "1.2828"  "-0.458"  "0.0862"
[1] "220"     "1.2784"  "-0.4606" "0.0886" 
[1] "230"     "1.2753"  "-0.4531" "0.0888" 
[1] "240"     "1.2717"  "-0.4512" "0.0902" 
[1] "251"     "1.2683"  "-0.4454" "0.0908" 
[1] "260"     "1.2657"  "-0.4398" "0.0911" 
[1] "270"     "1.263"   "-0.4336" "0.0913"
```

Will I be able to apply Peaks-Over-Thresholds on this data, in order to compare equivalent results in different events?

I have mainly used the `POT` package, but also `evir` to get the table with a selection of thresholds.